# Ссылка в ПДФ в "новом окне"

Tags: вёрстка, pdf, ссылки

ТАков вопрос - Можно ли в ПДФ документе делать такие ссылки, которые будут открывать НОВОЕ окно, как это в случае _blank с HTML ?

Answer (score 1):

PDF файлы это обычные медиафайлы, обрабатываемые различными способами в зависимости от настроек браузера пользователя и установки подключаемых модулей или программ. Обычно в самих программах должны быть такие настройки как открывать ссылки.

Comment: НЕт, я не столкнулся с подобными настройками даже в Acrobat. Думаю, можно закодть такие ссылки при помощи генерации моего PDF чеерз PHP иил еще как-то .. но это будет гораздо менее удобно, тк. сам ПДФ полиграфического качества, а из генераторов такие не выводят ... =\